# genearate week series using given range by specified order in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date-range, python-datetime, python-dateutil

start_dt= 2015-07-22

end_dt= 2016-07-22

so, my aim is to create a sequence by using start_dt and end_dt by one week difference.

I want output like this.

'2015-07-22' ,'2015-08-05' , '2015-08-19'...., end_dt

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats wrong with that question.

Comment: can i know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
start = date(2015, 7, 22)
end = date(2016, 7, 22)
diff = end-start      

for i in range(0, diff.days, 14):
    print(start)
    start += timedelta(days=14)
```

Comment: @neeraja You need to be more specific in what you're asking for in your question and also you **should** have a go yourself.